# How to write csv to another disk in ubuntu by pandas?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, ubuntu

I'm new to ubuntu. In my directory `/home/admin/mxc/newdata`, there is a python file `test.py` to write csv. But I don't have space to write on this directory. I need to write it to /dev/sda6/export. How to do it?

`test.py` contents:

```
import pandas as pd

sales = [{'account': 'Jones LLC', 'Jan': 150, 'Feb': 200, 'Mar': 140},
         {'account': 'Alpha Co',  'Jan': 200, 'Feb': 210, 'Mar': 215},
         {'account': 'Blue Inc',  'Jan': 50,  'Feb': 90,  'Mar': 95 }]
df = pd.DataFrame(sales)
df.to_csv('/export/test.csv',index=False)
```

Comment: replacing `/export/test.csv` with `/dev/sda6/export` doesn't work?

Comment: Is `/dev/sda6` mounted? If not, you need something like `mount /dev/sda6 /export` before you can write to the disk. Note that `/export` will need to be a directory already.

Comment: @Seanny123 IOError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/dev/sda6/export'

Comment: This isn't really a Python question.  You can't write anything to that disk until you mount it, and you can't write anything to that directory until you create it.

Comment: @danielunderwood mount: only root can do that

Comment: You typically need root to mount. `sudo mount /dev/sda6 /export` should do it.

Comment: @danielunderwood mount: /dev/sda6 is already mounted or /export busy
 /dev/sda6 is already mounted on /export

Comment: Does your script work now that it appears `/dev/sda6` is mounted as `/export`?

Comment: That means that you either have already mounted `/dev/sda6` or already have something mounted on `/export` (or it could be both). Look at what's in `/export` and see if it's what should be. If not, pick another directory to mount it at.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is to go a few directories back, then forward, do "../../../path" however many directories back you need to go